# Meteor defer - effect on reactivity

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor

I have a `Meteor.defer` inside an `autorun`.

```
this.autorun(() => {
  Meteor.defer(() => {
    functionThatUsesASessionVariable();
  });
});
```

This autorun does not re-execute when the Session variable changes.

Removing the `defer`, it does re-execute when the Session variable changes.

```
this.autorun(() => {
  functionThatUsesASessionVariable();
});
```

But I do actually want the defer behavior as well as the reactivity. Is there a way to get both?

====

(Right now my best play is just put a `Session.get('sessionVar')` in the beginning of the `autorun`, not assigned to anything, just to trigger the reactivity.)

```
this.autorun(() => {
  Session.get('sessionVar');
  Meteor.defer(() => {
    functionThatUsesASessionVariable();
  });
});
```

(But this obviously isn't great because it's better if the reactivity comes directly from the function's dependencies, which can change over time)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.autorun(() => {
  if (Session.get('yourVar') ){
    Meteor.defer(() => {
      functionThatUsesASessionVariable();
    });
  }
});
```

otherwise the autorun may not register the dependency on the Session variable.